# Undefined local variable or method `firewatir' for main:Object (N ameError)

Tags: ruby, firewatir

Having trouble running the Ruby script getting the below error message :

```
undefined local variable or method `firewatir' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Following versions :

```
Ruby187\bin>ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-10-12 patchlevel 371) [i386-mingw32]

Ruby187\bin>gem -v
1.8.24

Ruby187\bin>gem install firewatir
Successfully installed firewatir-1.9.4
```

- Firefox version 3.5
- installed JSSh 1.0

Script

```
require 'firewatir'
require 'win32ole'
```

Answer (score 0):

[firewatir](http://rubygems.org/gems/firewatir) is dead. The last release was in 2011. If you want to drive Firefox, use [watir-webdriver](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver).

Comment: C:\Ruby187\bin>ruby add_mem1.rb
add_mem1.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- watir (LoadError)
        from add_mem1.rb:1  NOW GETTING THIS ERROR MESSAGE AFTER installing gem install watir-webdriver-0.6.4.gem

Comment: @RubyFinder Upgrade your Ruby. Its too old.